# Planner ID seemingly not set

Tags: ros, rospy

I am using `rospy`.

I have a strange situation where the output is not expected.

Here is what I tried:

```
self.robot.arm.moveit_group.set_planner_id = "RRTConnectkConfigDefault"
```

What the output that I am getting is:

```
(Pdb) self.robot.arm.moveit_group.get_planner_id()
*** AttributeError: 'MoveGroupInterface' object has no attribute 'get_planner_id'
```

Not sure what could be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use something like this:

```
self.robot.arm.moveit_group.set_planner_id("RRTConnectkConfigDefault")
```

I hope that it will help you to move on in the interesting moveit stuff!